# How to show search result using user control window in windows application?

Tags: c#

My project is standalone application. I want to show my search result using user control window. so I added user control to my project. and I wrote code for it attached to form. It attached properly. But I want show my search result using that user control window's text box so how can i do this. Please help me
in form1

```
tr.rtnTxtMake = text;
```

user control

```
string txtMake;

public string rtnTxtMake
{
    get { return txtMake; }
    set { txtMake = value; }
}
```

This is my code; how do I show this text? It's not working with `txt_ree.Text = txtMake.ToString()`;

Comment: Won't `myTextBox.Text = "The search result";` do it? What have your tried? Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: I pass my search result into user control window myTextBox.Text =text.ToString(); but it not display. please help me.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code part. Of what type is the `text` variable?

Comment: Since `txtMake` is a `string` already, it makes no sense to "convert" it to a `string` with `ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a `TextBox` called `makeTextBox` in your user control, create a property like this

```
public string TextMake
{
    get { return makeTextBox.Text; }
    set { makeTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

Now you can assign a text to you user control like this (assuming that it is called `tr`):

```
tr.TextMake = "some text";
```

It will directly be assigned to the TextBox through the property. No need for a local variable that stores the text.